# How to make Bootstrap readonly input field look like normal text?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a field in my html page like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
```

I would like it to look like normal text between `<p>` tags. Please help me CSS wizards.

Comment: What have you tried? Show your work/code in your post please. You need to override all the styles that `.form-control` applies to an `<input>`. It might be easier to remove `.form-control` and style the `<input>` with your own class.

Comment: Any reason why you can't just use `<p>` tags? If not try just adding the css `border: none; background-color: transparent;` to it

Answer (score 40, accepted):

you can try this

**CSS**

```
input[readonly]{
  background-color:transparent;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

if you want to use with a class you can try this one

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control classname" value="Demo" readonly />
```

**CSS**

```
input[readonly].classname{
  background-color:transparent;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

if you want to make the `<input>` look like inline text (resizing the input element) please check this fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/Tanbi/xyL6fphm/ and please dont forget calling jquery js library

Comment: you need some javascript for this. you can find a sample in this fiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/Tanbi/xyL6fphm/](https://jsfiddle.net/Tanbi/xyL6fphm/) **PS:** i used jquery1.12.2 in this fiddle

Comment: You should probably add that to your answer as it appears the OP wants to make the `<input>` look like inline text.

Comment: I also added padding-left: 0;

Comment: for who still doesn't work, try to add !important on your css code. But use it carefully, because it can overiding your css style

Answer (score 14):

I realise the question is about Bootstrap 3, but it might be good to know that Bootstrap 4 now has this out of the box: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#readonly-plain-text

```
<div class="form-group row">
<label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
  <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="staticEmail" value="email@example.com">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

in addition to the accepted answer, I found that the following style works a bit better:

```
input[readonly] {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;

    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Bootstrap introduces a shadow that one may want to hide.

Comment: I also added padding-left: 0;

Comment: also add `outline: 0`

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Show your text" readonly style="border: 0px;" />
```

That should work

Answer (score 1):

**Bootstrap 5** has `form-control-plaintext` class for that:

```
<input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="email"/>
```