# ASP.Net Tag Helpers - Show Label with Actual Attribute Value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, tag-helpers

How can I display the value of an attribute in a label using tag helpers? I want to display created timestamp, but when I use the below code it just displays "Created" twice instead of "Created" and the actual timestamp.

```
 <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Created" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <label asp-for="Created" class="form-control"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Result:**
Created Created

**Desired Result:**
Created 04/13/2017 12:00:00

Comment: Why were you expecting it to behave differently with the same asp-for attribute?

Comment: @Charlie What do I need to change to specify I want the data value, not the display name?

Answer (score 3):

You could probably just dump it, assuming you are using razor:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Created" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    @Created
</div>
```

Comment: OK, this is actually what I tested after posting the question. Just thought there may be a more elegant "tag helper" way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

If this needs to be placed within a form with the value posted back, you'll need an input (or use [@Charlie's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43401561/7311767) answer and an extra hidden input for your Created property):

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Created" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input asp-for="Created" class="form-control my-label-class" type="datetime" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Refer to [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36574484/how-to-make-bootstrap-readonly-input-field-look-like-normal-text) to create the css.